# Plotting frequent itemsets and support

Tags: r, plot, data-mining

I want to create a plot comparing the number of frequent itemsets obtained according to the changing value of minimum support. How to do that?

```
ecParam1  = new("ECparameter", "confidence" = 0.8, "support" = 0.2) 
ecParam2  = new("ECparameter", "confidence" = 0.8, "support" = 0.3) 
ecParam3  = new("ECparameter", "confidence" = 0.8, "support" = 0.4) 

# Discovery of frequent itemsets
fsets1 <- eclat(Mushroom,ecParam1)
fsets2 <- eclat(Mushroom,ecParam2)
fsets3 <- eclat(Mushroom,ecParam3)

# Display the number of found itemsets for each parameter
length(fsets1) # Output: 38961
length(fsets2) # Output: 25735
length(fsets3) # Output: 533
```

For example here I got the 3 values relative to support of `0.2`, `0.3` and `0.4`.

Comment: What is `new` supposed to do? Are you working in `s4`?! If yes, what is `ECParameter` supposed to do? Are you using any packages? Also include a sample of what kind of plot you would like to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Make a two variable data frame out of this: x (support) and y (no. of frequent itemsets).

Then plot that data frame.